# Can I Use Multiple ItemProps in a Span Tag for schema.org Rich Snippets?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, rich-snippets

Let's say I have the following sentence I want to add rich snippets to:

> I live and work in New York

Since New York is both my residency and the city where I work in, I would theoretically want to tag the line like this using schema.org standards:

```
<div itemscope itemtype = 'http://schema.org/Person'>I live and work in 
<span itemprop = 'homeLocation'  itemprop = 'workLocation'>New York</span></div>
```

Is it valid to have 2 itemprops in one span tag?  If not, will the below work?

```
<div itemscope itemtype = 'http://schema.org/Person'>I live and work in 
<span itemprop = 'homeLocation'><span itemprop = 'workLocation'>New York
</span></span></div>
```

Comment: May I ask why you rolled back the edit?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The usual HTML way would be to use *one* attribute and separate several values with space characters.

Looking into the Microdata specification, you’ll notice that this is the case for the [`itemprop` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute), too:

> The `itemprop` attribute, if specified, must have a value that is an **unordered set of unique space-separated tokens** […]

So this should be correct:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  I live and work in <span itemprop="homeLocation workLocation">New York</span>
</div>
```

(Note: If using `itemprop` values as CSS selector, use [`[att~=val]` instead of `[att=val]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933394/1591669).)

Comment: what about `property`, does that the same?

Comment: @deadManN: Yes, RDFa’s [`property` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-rdfa-core-20150317/#A-property) can also take multiple values, separated by white space.

Comment: You noted a valuable technique using [attribute selectors](https://devdocs.io/css/attribute_selectors). Those who want to style either or, or both, can use `[attr*=value]` with case-insensitivity, e.g. `[itemprop*=location i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet of code I posted does not work, but the second does.  Google has a rich snippets [page tester](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) which is pretty useful for code validation