# News item in Schema.org

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm currently working on a **news page** for a website. Since I don't find any news example on http://schema.org/, I was wondering what's the best Schema.org type for this?

```
<li>
  <time>2015-12-31<time>
  <div>
    <h2>News title</h2>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Should I even bother adding Microdata?

**What I currently have:**

```
<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <time itemprop="datePublished">2015-12-31<time>
  <div>
    <h2 itemprop="headline">News title</h2>
    <div class="content" itemprop="description">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Is `Article` appropriate?
Should I use `headline` or `name`?
Should I use `description` or `articleBody`?

Comment: I would use `HTML5` in combinaton with this. Don't use a div when you can use the `article` tag for a news item.

Comment: I didn't used `article` since The `li` are already in an `article` tag. Should I put an article in an article?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Schema.org type `Article`](http://schema.org/Article) is appropriate, as its description says (bold emphasis mine):

> An article, such as a **news article** or piece of investigative report. […]

But you can even be more specific by using the [`NewsArticle` type](http://schema.org/NewsArticle) (note that by using this type, your news post is [*also*](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69598/17633) an `Article` and *also* an `CreativeWork` and *also* a `Thing`, so you don’t "miss" anything).

Regarding [`description`](http://schema.org/description) vs. [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody): Just like their descriptions say, you would use `description` for a "short description" and `articleBody` for the "actual body" of the news article.

Regarding [`name`](http://schema.org/name) vs. [`headline`](http://schema.org/headline): they would often have the same content, so if you don’t know/need this difference, you could either use [both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669) (`itemprop="headline name"`) or simply go with `name` (as this is what every item/`Thing` can have, while `headline` is an addition for `CreativeWork` only).

It has nothing to do with the Microdata, but you might want to use the `article` element for each news post in this list. If it’s a list, for example, of recent news posts, the parent [should probably not be `article` but `section`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26887006/1591669):

```html
<section>
  <h1>Recent news posts</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><article><!-- news post 1 --></article></li>
    <li><article><!-- news post 2 --></article></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

And an `article` could look like:

```
<li>
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
    <header>
      <time itemprop="datePublished">2015-12-31<time>
      <h2 itemprop="name">News title</h2>
    </header>

    <div itemprop="description"><!-- news teaser --></div>
    <!-- or "articleBody" instead of "description" if it’s the full content -->

  </article>
</li>
```