# Is it good to put HTML5 Microdata on preview blocks?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata

Consider this example:

```
<section id="news_block_left" class="block" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <a href="http://dev.com/index.php?controller=NewsList" title="News" itemprop="url">
        <h2 class="title_block" itemprop="name">News</h2>
    </a>
    <div class="block_content">
        <ul class="news-list">
            <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
                <a href="http://dev.com/index.php?id_news=7&controller=News" title="News Title1" itemprop="url">
                    <span><span itemprop="datePublished">2015-03-30</span> <em itemprop="headline">News Title1</em></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
                <a href="http://dev.com/index.php?id_news=8&controller=News" title="T230 series (1999–2006)" itemprop="url">
                    <span><span itemprop="datePublished">2015-03-08</span> <em itemprop="headline">T230 series (1999–2006)</em></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <meta itemprop="numberOfItems" content="2">
        <a class="more_news" href="http://dev.com/index.php?controller=NewsList" title="More news">
            <span>More news</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

This block exists in the sidebar, it doesn't contain full news element data, only a couple of link this them.

The link "More news" leads to a more complete list with more markup (but still only a list with links to the actual articles).

Is there a benefit in putting Microdata on such preview lists? Or is Microdata intended for complete pages (complete news page with body, product page, etc.)?

P.S. Don't mind the unfriendly URLs, it's only dev version.

Comment: Another side note: As you give this teaser news list the URL of the full news list, the `numberOfItems` should probably be the number of *all* entries, not just of the entries displayed as teaser.

Comment: Hmm maybe you're right, I didn't understand what the prop description implied.

Comment: Yeah, I think the description could be more clear. I opened a ticket: [numberOfItems clarification](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s fine. It’s in no way required to use Microdata only for certain content. The same goes for the vocabulary Schema.org. The more the merrier.

Thanks to using Schema.org’s `url` property for each `NewsArticle` item, consumers have the chance to learn that these items have separate URLs with probably (but not necessarily) more relevant content.

On a side note: You [might want to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932165/1591669) use `name` instead of `headline` (or `name` in addition). The `name` property, as it can be used on all Schema.org types, has probably more support than the `headline` property, which can only be used on `CreativeWork` types. (Currently it [gets discussed](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/pull/423) if `headline` should be marked superseded by `name`.)