# Structured data on product category pages?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I have added structured data to the product pages of my website. Would it also be beneficial to also add the structured data to the category pages? i.e. the pages that show all products within a certain product category group?

My thought is yes, as I'm describing what that page is displaying. The only doubt I have is that I'm only displaying a subset of the information that's on the full product page.  E.g. I don't have a `itemprop='description'` entry on the category page.  But I would assume/hope that because I have `itemprop="url"` for each product on the category page, that the search engines will be smart enough to tie the two together …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It can be beneficial to have the structured data also on category pages, [in sidebars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765466/1591669), on search result pages, etc., for [various reasons](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54703/17633). The more the merrier.

It’s no problem to specify only a subset of the content. Neither Microdata nor Schema.org *require* any properties.

And yes, by using Schema.org’s `url` property, you give consumers the chance to learn

- that the two items are about the same thing, and
- that they might find more properties about the item by following the URL.

(If, or which, consumers actually do this is another topic.)