# Is it possible to have a more than one "itemprop" on the same item? (not nested)

Tags: html, microdata

I was wondering if it was possible to have more than one **itemprop** set for the same element.

E.g. I have a telephone that works also as fax and I would like to set a span with itemprops *telephone* and *faxNumber* (using the [Product schema](http://schema.org/Organization)). Is it possible to do something like that? 
I'm pretty sure that this doesn't work as it should

```
<span itemprop="telephone">
     <span itemprop="faxNumber">(...)</span>
</span>
```

So, will something like this work instead?

```
<span itemprop="telephone" itemprop="faxNumber">(...)</span>
```

If not, is there a way to bypass the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I Use Multiple ItemProps in a Span Tag for schema.org Rich Snippets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198956/can-i-use-multiple-itemprop-attributes-in-an-element)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the answer. Thank you very much