# What's the best way to nest non-visible Schema.org properties in Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Assuming I have a marked-up blog post using Microdata, is this the correct way to include the nested `publisher` person? I don't want to display the publisher name, but it's required by Google Structured Data Testing Tool. I'm happy with the markup for the nested `author` person, but using `div`, a layout tag, simply for nesting an invisible meta tag seems wrong.

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <h1 itemprop="headline">Post heading goes here</h1>

  <meta itemprop="keywords" content="alpha, beta, gamma" />

  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemid="philbalchin">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Phil Balchin" />
  </div>

  <p itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemid="philbalchin">
    <span itemprop="name">Phil Balchin</span>
  </p>

</article>
```

Is it possible to chain `itemprop` names, i.e., `itemprop="publisher.name"`, or something similar to avoid unnecessary tags?

Answer (score 3):

As the author and the publisher is the same person in your case, you could use [both properties in the same `itemprop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669):

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <h1 itemprop="headline">Post heading goes here</h1>

  <meta itemprop="keywords" content="alpha, beta, gamma" />

  <div itemprop="author publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemid="philbalchin">
    <span itemprop="name">Phil Balchin</span>
  </div>

</article>
```

But if that’s not the case, adding a `div` that contains `meta` and `link` elements is the appropriate alternative, exactly because it’s a meaningless element.

Comment: That's a handy tip, I did not know you combine nested properties like that.