# Gmail Inbox View Action - "A value for the url field is required."

Tags: gmail, html-email, schema.org, microdata, google-schemas

I'm trying to get the markup correct for Gmail inbox actions for resetting a password. I'm using the [Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/).

My markup looks like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Reset password instructions"/>
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ViewAction">
    <meta itemprop="target" content="https://www.example.com/users/password/new?token=123"/>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Reset Your Password"/>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Visit our site to reset your password."/>
</div>
```

The above markup returns the error:

> A value for the url field is required.

But I can't figure out how that `url` field should be inserted into the markup. Even [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action) fails their markup validator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Not sure if this is just an error with their testing tool, or if this is really a new requirement that’s not documented.)

You could provide the `url` property [in addition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669) to the `target` property. Also note that you [have to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) use a `link` element (instead of a `meta` element) if the value is a URL.

So it would be:

```html
<link itemprop="target url" href="https://www.example.com/users/password/new?token=123" />
```

This reports no errors in Google’s email markup tester.